# Can a CHAR(10) column be ALTER-ed to be VARCHAR or INT in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, constraints, alter

Somebody created a column in our database where, originally, only 10-digit phone numbers were allowable (thus, the datatype `CHAR(10)` was used).

We're now trying to change the database to allow for something our system wasn't built to handle - international numbers with a variable length of phone number.

Originally, this database was ONLY handling PBX requests which passed NANP numbers ONLY (all international numbers were translated to a termination number before reaching the platform).  Now there are going to be web requests that show the pre-translation number and we don't have the resources (time/staff) to do what we want, which would be creating a new table to handle the front end, then creating a relationship in the back end table.

Our database is replicated to three other servers (one on-site and two off-site on a VPN) and in the past this has sometimes caused a problem for us (So I'm told).  Also, ALL values are currently 10 digit numbers, and there are ~100,000 records in the table.  And to reiterate, we're using SQL Server (I believe 2008).

Are we able to change this datatype to a `VARCHAR` or `INT` value with an `ALTER` statement WITHOUT LOSING DATA, and secondarily, are we able to do this without turning off replication?

Additionally, would the correct code be one of the following two SQL commands, where the column name is `DNIS`?

```
ALTER DNISConfig
ALTER COLUMN [DNIS] VARCHAR(50)
```

or

```
ALTER DNISConfig
ALTER COLUMN [DNIS] INT
```

Comment: You could easily try the alters on a table you whip up.  It's a lot of writeup for something you could confirm in a few minutes.  The replication part of this depends on both the version of SQL Server and the type of replication.

Comment: I don't have the authority to create new tables on our server, dept head is 3 hours ahead of me so I couldn't ask.  This was faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct:

```
ALTER TABLE DNISConfig  
 ALTER COLUMN [DNIS]  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Will change the column to a VARCHAR.

My opinion, phone numbers are not INTs, so the VARCHAR option would be preferable.

Comment: Phone numbers aren't `INT`s, no, but the standard for phone numbers is a max of 15 digits (50 is way to large, and they should be stored unformatted).  I haven't been able to tell if that's supposed to contain the country code, but that should be a separate column anyways.

Comment: I would agree, but I might be instructed to do either, so I included both cases in case there was a difference.  To confirm, either way would keep the existing data intact?